# How do you find which points connect to other points

Tags: qgis

I have points that I have created from vector lines. To be more specific these points are end and start points of vector lines. But what I want to do now is identify which points connect to each other without manually doing this. Is this possible?

Comment: _without manually doing_ what ?

Answer (score 1):

**How to identify points that fall on the the same line:**

1. Add a unique ID to the line layer. Use the Field Calculator to add a new numerical field, with the expression `@row_number`.
2. Do a spatial join between the point layer and the line layer. Now all the points that fall on line share an attribute.
3. Use the shared attribute to identify which points are connected by lines. Eg, you could apply a categorized style using this field.

Comment: i suppose that was the question ... lol